# Python tkinter difference between spinbox and optionmenu

Tags: python, user-interface, listbox, tkinter, optionmenu

I was just wondering what the difference between a spin box and option menu is?
They both seem to be a drop down list displaying different options. 
I'm a beginner in programming, so will appreciate it if someone could explain without going into too much technical details.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoted from [developer.gnome.org](https://developer.gnome.org/hig-book/2.91/controls-spin-boxes.html.en)...

> Use spin boxes for numerical input only. Use a list or option menu
>   when you need the user to select from fixed data sets of other types.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can spin box only show numerical values then?

Comment: @user2192517 No, though it is sort of a matter of etiquette.